# Race issue with reading CallLog from provider

Tags: android

Just a bit of app background, this app allows users to click on a number from the application and redirects it to the phone app.

And once the call is done, it will redirect the user back to the app then it retrieves the call information of this particular number (such as timestamp, duration, etc)

However, I come across a race issue where I don't get the latest call log on some phones; meaning Android writes the call log after the app reads the CallLog provider (I can't be certain for how big this window gap).

To put this in simple technical flow:

1. User click the phone number on the app
2. Broadcast receiver is triggered
3. App start Phone activity
4. Call ends after some period
5. Broadcast receiver listen to the event
6. Get call details

With this in place, is there some steps that I missed? or do you have a better solution to handle this?

Thanks.